# org.hibernate.StaleStateException whenever nested transaction is started

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with Hiberate which I'm unable to figure out. The scenario is:

1. New session and a transaction is started
2. Entity with version lets say 10 is loaded
3. New transaction is started via @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
4. When this new transaction is commited and flushes, entity version is raised to 11
5. The original transaction commits, flushes but doesn't know that version was raised and so tries to update where version is 10, but version is now already 11, so it fails with

Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update COMMON.WORKSPACE set VERSION=?, MODEL=? where ID=? and VERSION=?

I don't know where's the problem. I'm guessing the new transaction shouldn't open new session? Or should the flush in the new transaction propagate the version change to the original session?

Hibernate version is 5.6.

I've tried changing Flush Mode from AUTO to COMMIT, but that made things even worse.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can merge changes from the second transaction into the first transaction's session manually like below,

   ```
    @Transactional
   public void updateEntityInSameTransaction() {
    // Load entity in the current session
    Entity entity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, entityId);

    // Perform some operations on the entity

    // Start a new transaction
    updateEntityInNewTransaction(entity);

    // Merge changes made in the second transaction into the first transaction's session
    entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).merge(entity);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateEntityInNewTransaction(Entity entity) {
    // Update entity in the new transaction
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
   ```
2. Use the same session for both transactions: Ensure that both transactions operate within the same Hibernate session. This can be achieved by either avoiding the use of REQUIRES_NEW for the second transaction or by explicitly sharing the session context between the two transactions.